# You may have an infinite update loop in a component render function, caused by side effect in method

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, mixins

I've solved my issue, but I don't understand it (or maybe I do).

I created an error handler plugin, basic example:

**main.js**

```
const bugStore = {
  state: [],
  addToState(bug) {
    this.state.push(bug);
  }
};

const ErrorLoggerPlugin = {
  install(Vue) {
    const app = new Vue({
      data: {
        bugStore: bugStore
      },
      methods: {
        bug(bug) {
          // Necessary to prevent re-rendering of components
          //setTimeout(() => {
          this.bugStore.addToState(bug);
          //});
        }
      }
    });
    Vue.prototype.$bug = app.bug;
    
  }
};

Vue.use(ErrorLoggerPlugin);

new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  components: {
    App
  },
  template: "<App/>",
  render: (h) => h(App)
});
```

**App.vue**

```
<template>
  <div>
    <img alt="Vue logo" src="./assets/logo.png" />
    {{ $injector("hello world") }}
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  name: "App",
  components: {},
  methods: {
    $injector(val) {
      try {
        breakme();
      } catch {
        this.$bug("anything");
      }
      return val;
    },
  },
};
</script>
```

By doing this, I end up with an infinite loop in the render function of App.vue

I won't be using a method in a template. I know to avoid this. But I'm trying to understand why this causes the component to re-render.

If you uncomment the setTimeout in main.js it prevents the issue.

Understanding setTimeout, this allows the method to return the value before further execution of the bug handler plugin is performed.

After a good nights rest, I think I have an idea of what's going on. But this also begs the question, what would be a better way to handle this?

**What's happening:**

*I think that when the template uses this method call it creates notification dependencies within the stack of the method, and therefore the component becomes reactive to the state of the plugins store.
And if I wrap it in a setTimeout, that related dependency isn't executed until the current stack clears.*

https://codesandbox.io/s/modest-babbage-cjuw71?file=/src/main.js

So I suppose I need to re-think how I'm handling this. I have a global error handler that doesn't cause issues, but there are times that I want to handle an issue intentionally and report this to the notification engine. In fact, it may not even be an error. This can be anything.

**UPDATE**

I created a functional component to replace the functionality of what was previously seen done with a method. Same issue.

**UPDATE**

I removed the `new Vue` from the plugin as suggested by this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/75625507/1447679

But in my case I needed reactivity in another portion of the app. That component, I referenced the state of the bug store in its own data attributes to make it reactive, and everything worked out.

**TAKEAWAY**

Anything that's part of the rendering of a component, unless otherwise specified with v-once, will create a notification/dependency tree from anything it touches. So if the method changes the state, even seemingly not related/tied to the particular component, it will react to this change and re-render the component.

Comment: It would greatly help if you could provide an online reproduction so we can debug too. It's hard to understand the entire flow of your code by just reading it.

Comment: @Kapcash agreed. I'll work on that

Comment: @Kapcash I've updated the question and included a sandbox. I'm getting to the bottom of this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found out the problem was that you create a new Vue app in your plugin.
This is causing a kind of circular reactive dependency between your main app, and the plugin one, which provoke the infinite render loop.

If you simply avoid creating this internal Vue app (because you don't need it), the problem is gone:

```js
const bugStore = {
  state: [],
  addToState(bug) {
    this.state.push(bug);
  }
};

const ErrorLoggerPlugin = {
  install(Vue) {
    Vue.prototype.$bug = (bug) => {
      bugStore.addToState(bug);
      console.log("bug added");
    }
  }
};
```

Comment: Yep, I tried this last night but unfortunately I do need reactivity on the store. This is often the case. Try to strip down the question for clarity and some of the little details get lost. I did find a solution though. In the portion of the app that I needed reactive, I `$set` it's own internal reference before mount to the state of the plugin. Now it works, don't need setTimeout, and it doesn't use an app for the plugin.

Comment: If you need a reactive store, why not considering vuex or pinia libraries?

Comment: I had already tried this. It did the same thing. I liked the idea of the plugin being independent and not coupled with anything as well. I originally passed a reference to a vuex action in settings (much of this was stripped out of example in question). The lesson I've learned is the level of dependency/notification tree that's wired in when a method/prop/computed is responsible (or anything really) to render part of a template.  I suppose you could call it a side effect, much like mutating something in a computed property.